# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_pricebase, Line 13 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

> how to solve this kind of probe help me please:

**error:**

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_pricebase, Line 13 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

---

and my trigger is :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_pricebase]
ON  [dbo].[tbl_model2]        
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
   BEGIN

                DECLARE @price_base NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT tbl_model2.price_base FROM tbl_model2)
                DECLARE @tipid  int = (SELECT tbl_model2.id FROM tbl_model2)


                INSERT INTO tbl_price_history (tbl_price_history.price_base,tbl_price_history.tipid)
                VALUES (@price_base, @tipid )

    END
```

Comment: Do either of the select queries in the first two lines return more than one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you want

```
alter trigger[dbo].[trg_pricebase] on [dbo].[tbl_model2]after update as 
begin
    insert into dbo.tbl_price_history (
        price_base,
        tipid
    ) select
        price_base,
        id
    from
        inserted
end
```

You have two basic problems. 
Firstly, to read only the rows affected by the update statement, use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables.
Secondly, a trigger can fire off multiple rows, you can't assume there will just be one affected row.

Comment: thank you for resolve, this query Help to achieve the correct way,
but i have run this query when " A specific field " changed in [dbo].[tbl_model2] table.
Is it possible?

Comment: @MohsenShahbazi look up the `update()` and  `columns_updated()` functions.

Comment: please link to references

Answer (score 0):

Execute following [sub]queries to see what query return more than one row:

```
SELECT tbl_model2.price_base FROM tbl_model2
SELECT tbl_model2.id FROM tbl_model2
```

I assume you want to insert into *history table the old values (table deleted) or the new values (table inserted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_pricebase]
ON  [dbo].[tbl_model2]        
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO tbl_price_history (price_base, tipid)
    SELECT  price_base, tipid
    FROM    deleted -- for old values
    -- or FROM  inserted -- for new values
END
```

References: [inserted and deleted table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to use the method what you had followed in your query when you assign a value to a variable.

```
DECLARE @price_base NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT tbl_model2.price_base FROM tbl_model2)
```

This select statement within bracket returns a resultset, not a single value, which cannot be stored into a variable (except table data typed variable). Don't practice this method, this will always end up with errors.

You should always use

```
select top 1 @price_base = price_base FROM tbl_model2
```

when you insert multiple rows, assigning values into a variable inside a trigger, will lead you to lose data.